# Reuse same bunch of statements several times

Tags: android, reusability

I 'm sorry if this is too dumb and simple but I am out of every option I can think of.
It is not even real programming. But I have several lines in a switch statement which I 've to use several times. I can't think of any way in which I can store all this code (these lines) and reuse whenever i want.

```
        case 0:
            bcolor=Color.rgb(240, 255, 255);//Azure
            break;
        case 1:
            bcolor=Color.BLACK;
            break;
        case 2:
            bcolor=Color.BLUE;
            break;
        case 3:
            bcolor=Color.rgb(165, 42, 42);//Brown
            break;
        case 4:
            bcolor=Color.rgb(255, 127, 50);//Coral
            break;
        case 5:
            bcolor=Color.rgb(00, 255, 255);//cyan
            break;
        case 6:
            bcolor=Color.rgb(255, 00, 255);//Fuchsia
            break;
        case 7:
            bcolor=Color.rgb(255, 215, 00);//Gold
            break;
        case 8:
            bcolor=Color.GRAY;
            break;
        case 9:
            bcolor=Color.GREEN;
            break;
        case 10:
            bcolor=Color.rgb(173, 255, 47);//Green Yellow
            break;
        case 11:
            bcolor=Color.rgb(00, 255, 00);//Lime
            break;
        case 12:
            bcolor=Color.MAGENTA;
            break;
        case 13:
            bcolor=Color.rgb(80, 00, 00);//Maroon
            break;
        case 14:
            bcolor=Color.rgb(80, 80, 00);//Olive
            break;
        case 15:
            bcolor=Color.rgb(255, 165, 00);//Orange
            break;
        case 16:
            bcolor=Color.rgb(255, 192, 203);//pink
            break;
        case 17:
            bcolor=Color.rgb(80, 00, 80);//purple
            break;
        case 18:
            bcolor=Color.RED;
            break;
        case 19:
            bcolor=Color.rgb(244, 196, 30);//Saffron
            break;
        case 20:
            bcolor=Color.rgb(192, 192, 192);//Silver
            break;
        case 21:
            bcolor=Color.rgb(238, 82, 238);//Violet
            break;
        case 22:
            bcolor=Color.WHITE;
            break;
        case 23:
            bcolor=Color.YELLOW;
            break;
```

I have to use all these switch cases in several switch conditions. Isn't is possible to bind them in some kind of label or something. and just call them when I want to use...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more optimal solution that I have seen and used is to store all of these values in a map (**constant time complexity** for lookups):

```
public static Map<Integer, Integer> colorMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

static
{
    colorMap.put(0, Color.rgb(240, 255, 255));
    colorMap.put(1, Color.BLACK);
    colorMap.put(2, Color.BLUE);
    colorMap.put(3, Color.rgb(165, 42, 42));
    colorMap.put(4, Color.rgb(255, 127, 50));
    colorMap.put(5, Color.rgb(00, 255, 255));
    colorMap.put(6, Color.rgb(255, 00, 255));
    colorMap.put(7, Color.rgb(255, 215, 00));
    colorMap.put(8, Color.GRAY);
    colorMap.put(9, Color.GREEN);
    colorMap.put(10, Color.rgb(173, 255, 47));
    colorMap.put(11, Color.rgb(00, 255, 00));
    colorMap.put(12, Color.MAGENTA);
    colorMap.put(13, Color.rgb(80, 00, 00));
    colorMap.put(14, Color.rgb(80, 80, 00));
    colorMap.put(15, Color.rgb(255, 165, 00));
    colorMap.put(16, Color.rgb(255, 192, 203));
    colorMap.put(17, Color.rgb(80, 00, 80));
    colorMap.put(18, Color.RED);
    colorMap.put(19, Color.rgb(244, 196, 30));
    colorMap.put(20, Color.rgb(192, 192, 192));
    colorMap.put(21, Color.rgb(238, 82, 238));
    colorMap.put(22, Color.WHITE);
    colorMap.put(23, Color.YELLOW);
}


public static int getColor(int lookup)
{
    int color = colorMap.get(lookup);
    return color == null ? 0 : color;
}
```

Comment: @user2591556 glad I could help! Be sure to accept this answer if it works well for you (you will get +2 reputation).

Answer (score 2):

Wrap this code in a function and call the function:

```
public int getColor(int i)
{
    switch(i) {
        case 0:
            return Color.rgb(240, 255, 255);//Azure
        case 1:
            return Color.BLACK;
        case 2:
            return Color.BLUE;
        case 3:
            return Color.rgb(165, 42, 42);//Brown
        case 4:
            return Color.rgb(255, 127, 50);//Coral
        case 5:
            return Color.rgb(00, 255, 255);//cyan
        case 6:
            return Color.rgb(255, 00, 255);//Fuchsia
        case 7:
            return Color.rgb(255, 215, 00);//Gold
        case 8:
            return Color.GRAY;
        case 9:
            return Color.GREEN;
        case 10:
            return Color.rgb(173, 255, 47);//Green Yellow
        case 11:
            return Color.rgb(00, 255, 00);//Lime
        case 12:
            return Color.MAGENTA;
        case 13:
            return Color.rgb(80, 00, 00);//Maroon
        case 14:
            return Color.rgb(80, 80, 00);//Olive
        case 15:
            return Color.rgb(255, 165, 00);//Orange
        case 16:
            return Color.rgb(255, 192, 203);//pink
        case 17:
            return Color.rgb(80, 00, 80);//purple
        case 18:
            return Color.RED;
        case 19:
            return Color.rgb(244, 196, 30);//Saffron
        case 20:
            return Color.rgb(192, 192, 192);//Silver
        case 21:
            return Color.rgb(238, 82, 238);//Violet
        case 22:
            return Color.WHITE;
        case 23:
            return Color.YELLOW;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was creating a void method so it wasn't working. now it works perfectly...

Answer (score 2):

First it might be smart to define your colors in an XML file.

So create this file: `res/values/colors.xml`

And add colors like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="azure">#f0ffff</color>
    <color name="brown">#a52a2a</color>
</resources>
```

So then you can use them as:

> R.color.azure

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Color

Comment: But then also I will have to write each case each time i use it. I have uses same color cases like 5 times in my app. so I will have to write all 25 colors (case0 to case 24) every time.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
public int getColor(int option){
   switch(option){
   // switch statement in here
   }
   return bcolor;
}
```

And now you can call it like this:

```
int option = 12 // some option
int myColor = getColor(option);
```

Answer (score 0):

If they're the only cases in the switch statement, you can put them in a static function that returns an integer, and then call it (bcolor = MyClass.getColor(int switchVariable))

Answer (score 0):

As basdwarf said,

> Wrap this code in a function and call the function.

You can do this (I didnt take all your cases) :

```
private void awesomeColorFunction() {
        case 0:
            bcolor=Color.rgb(240, 255, 255);//Azure
            break;
        case 1:
            bcolor=Color.BLACK;
            break;
        case 2:
            bcolor=Color.BLUE;
            break;
}
```

then call it in your code simply like this :

```
awesomeColorFunction();
```

But the smartest way is certainly, as said Pewiity to put your colors in an xml file

Comment: I can't do  this. it shows "Syntax error on token "case", assert expected"

Comment: My bad, just forgot to add switch line. Just use basdward's answer, he updated it ;-)